# Nonparametric Bayesian analysis in R

Tags: r, bayesian, clustering, nonparametric

I am looking for a good tutorial on clustering data in `R` using hierarchical dirichlet process (HDP) (one of the recent and popular nonparametric Bayesian methods).

There is `DPpackage` (IMHO, the most comprehensive of all the available ones) in `R` for nonparametric Bayesian analysis. But I am unable to understand the examples provided in `R News` or in the package reference manual well enough to code HDP.

Any help or pointer is appreciated.

A C++ implementation of HDP for topic modeling is available [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/topicmodeling.html) (please look at the bottom for C++ code)

Answer (score 15):

Here are some online ressources I found interesting without going into detail (and I'm not a specialist of this topic):

- [Hierarchical Dirichlet Processes](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/faculty/mbeal/papers/hdp.pdf), by Teh et al. (2005)
- [Dirichlet Processes A gentle tutorial](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kbe/dp_tutorial.pdf), by El-Arini (2008)
- [Bayesian Nonparametrics](http://www.mit.edu/~9.520/spring10/Classes/class21_dirichlet_2010.pdf), by Rosasco (2010)
- [Non-parametric Bayesian Methods](http://learning.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/talks/uai05tutorial-b.pdf), by Ghahramani (2005)

The definitive reference seems to be

> N. Hjort, C. Holmes, P. Müller, and S.
>   Walker, editors. *[Bayesian
>   Nonparametrics](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item2707877/?site_locale=en_GB)*. Number 28 in
>   Cambridge Series in Statistical and
>   Probabilistic Mathematics. Cambridge
>   University Press, 2010.

About R, there seems to be some other packages worth to explore if the [DPpackage](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DPpackage/index.html) does not suit your needs, e.g. [dpmixsim](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dpmixsim/), [BHC](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/bioc-views/release/bioc/html/BHC.html), or [mbsc](http://www.stat.washington.edu/hoff/Code/MBSC/) found on [Rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org).

Comment: Thank you. Actually I just needed pointers for the R package. I appreciate your helpfulness! By the way, the book is awesome.

Comment: However, I will wait for someone to point me to an R package or tutorial that shows how to do HDP based modeling in R.

Comment: @suncoolsu I never tried those packages; so my contribution is just some googling (because I'm interested in using HDP in the future, but have no time for the moment -- this is the reason why I made my answer CW). I guess someone more used to those methods will provide insightful remarks.

Answer (score 13):

These two links provide some R (and C) code examples of implementing a DP normal mixture:

- http://ice.uchicago.edu/2008_presentations/Rossi/density_estimation_with_DP_priors.ppt
- http://www.duke.edu/~neelo003/r/DP02.r

Found another reference.  Chapter 15 has DP winbugs code:

- http://www.ics.uci.edu/~wjohnson/BIDA/BIDABook.html